# Python Requests cannot get other pages on same site

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Using the python `requests` module, I tried to send requests to [capitoltrades_politician_site](https://www.capitoltrades.com/politicians). There are multiple pages of featured politicians, however when I send requests to these pages via `?page=2` or using the params argument, I always receive the first page back.  I also tried adding `per_page=1000` (to show all politicians in one page), this didn't work either

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests
import time

payload = {'page': 2,
           'per_page': 100,}
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

session = requests.Session()

r = session.get('https://www.capitoltrades.com/politicians',headers=headers, params=payload)

print(r.url)

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
politicians = soup.find_all('a', class_='index-card-link')
print(len(politicians))

with open("test.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(soup.prettify())
```

I also attempted to explicitly use the link with `?per_page=1000` (this works fine on chrome), but it continued to return the HTML of page one with 12 politicians.  Any help is appreciated, would love to know if I'm doing something wrong with the `requests` library, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is rendered dynamically and loaded from an API. Because `requests` could only handle static response you have to focus on the API or instead use something like `selenium` to mimic a browser.

Iterate the pages and use the JSON response to extract your data.

###### Example

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

page = 1
data = []
while True:
    json_data = requests.get(f'https://bff.capitoltrades.com/politicians?per_page=96&page={page}&pageSize=96&metric=dateLastTraded&metric=countTrades&metric=countIssuers&metric=volume').json()
    data.extend(json_data.get('data'))
    if page == json_data.get('meta').get('paging').get('totalPages'):
        break
    else:
        page = page+1

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

|  | _politicianId | _stateId | party | partyOther | district | firstName | lastName | nickname | middleName | fullName | dob | gender | socialFacebook | socialTwitter | socialYoutube | website | chamber | committees | stats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | C001129 | ga | republican |  | 10 | Michael | Collins |  | Allen | Collins, Michael Allen Jr | 1967-07-02 | male |  | @MikeCollinsGA |  | https://collins.house.gov/ | house | ['hsii', 'hspw', 'hssy'] | {'dateLastTraded': '2024-01-08', 'countTrades': 6, 'countIssuers': 1, 'volume': 72500} |
| 1 | M001135 | nc | democrat |  | 6 | Kathy | Manning |  | Ellen | Manning, Kathy Ellen | 1956-12-03 | female |  | @RepKManning |  | https://manning.house.gov/ | house | ['hsed', 'hsfa'] | {'dateLastTraded': '2024-01-01', 'countTrades': 583, 'countIssuers': 168, 'volume': 17567122} |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 210 | G000579 | wi | republican |  | 8 | Michael | Gallagher | Mike | John | Gallagher, Michael John (Mike) | 1984-03-03 | male | RepMikeGallagher | @RepGallagher |  | https://gallagher.house.gov | house | ['hlig', 'hsas', 'hszs'] | {'dateLastTraded': '2021-03-25', 'countTrades': 1, 'countIssuers': 1, 'volume': 8000} |
| 211 | L000273 | nm | democrat |  | 3 | Teresa | Leger Fernandez |  | Isabel | Leger Fernandez, Teresa Isabel | 1959-07-01 | female |  | @RepTeresaLF |  | https://fernandez.house.gov/ | house | ['hsed', 'hsii', 'hsru'] | {'dateLastTraded': '2021-01-20', 'countTrades': 1, 'countIssuers': 1, 'volume': 32500} |

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how were you able to figure out that it was dynamic and know it was being loaded by an API?  Thank you!

Comment: First indicator, call up the website as a human in the browser and notice that a loading animation appears for the area. Second indicator, the content is not included in the response to the request. You can now use the browser's developer tools to look at the XHR Requests tab to see which data is being loaded from which resources. -> https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network